# How to run xml data(getting as the response from service) against a XSL and get html output in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xslt

I need to display the response of a service(getting as XML) in a row column way. We have an XSL file to do formatting. now I need to know how to do using C# 4.0
 I do not want to save the XML file or HTML.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/140505). You have not shown us what you have tried and what is not working.

Comment: XslTransform myXslTransform;
myXslTransform = new XslTransform();
myXslTransform.Load("solrtemplate.xsl");
myXslTransform.Transform("XMLInput", "HTMLOutPut"); Hi I was doing by this. But this required the response need to save as a file. I need it in a betterway.

Comment: In which format do you want to get the output, as a string? In general for running XSLT 1.0 transformations with .NET 4.0 see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx, for the possible output types see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wy7d6xd.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

if you have URL where you can get XML data, you have to:

- Download XML file with System.Net.WebClient
- Parse that XML file with System.Xml.XmlDocument.
- Now when you have parsed XML response, you can use StringBuilder or any other class to convert that XML to readable HTML.

Everything in made in memory without any temporary files creation.